# Java implementation of Conway's Game of Life with GUI

Tags: java, swing, game-of-life

I've implemented the Conway's Game of Life in Java, including a GUI. Here's the code of the two classes I wrote:

**`GameOfLife.java`**

```java
public class GameOfLife {

    public static void main(String[] args)  throws InterruptedException {

        Gui gui = new Gui();

        int [][] array = new int [71][71];

        //Field edge is getting filled up with '2'
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < array.length; j++){
                    array[i][j] = 2;
            }
        }

        //Field gets filled up with '0' = dead cells
        for(int i = 1; i < array.length - 1; i++){
            for(int j = 1; j < array.length - 1; j++){
                array[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
        //A glider
        array[9][5]=1;
        array[9][6]=1;
        array[9][7]=1;
        array[8][7]=1;
        array[7][6]=1;

        Gui.printingOut(array);

    }

    public static void applyRules(int[][] array) {
        int[][] newArray = new int[array.length][array.length];
        for(int y = 1; y < array.length - 1; y++) {
            for(int x = 1; x < array.length - 1; x++) {
                int neighbors = neighborsCounter(array, x, y);
                if(array[x][y] == 1) {
                    if((neighbors < 2) || (neighbors > 3)) {
                        newArray[x][y] = 0;
                    }
                    if((neighbors == 2) || (neighbors == 3)) {
                        newArray[x][y] = 1;
                    }
                }
                else if(array[x][y] == 0){
                    if(neighbors == 3) {
                        newArray[x][y] = 1;
                    }
                    else {
                        newArray[x][y] = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        for(int i = 1; i < array.length - 1; i++){
            for(int j = 1; j < array.length - 1; j++) {
                array[i][j] = newArray[i][j];
            }
        }

    }

    public static int neighborsCounter(int[][] array, int x, int y) {
        int neighbors = 0;
        for(int i = x - 1; i <= x + 1; i++) {
            for(int j = y - 1; j <= y + 1; j++) {
                if(array[i][j] == 1) {
                    neighbors = neighbors + 1;
                }
            }
        }

        if(array[x][y] == 1) {
            neighbors = neighbors - 1;
        }
        return neighbors;
    }

}
```

And here's the class for the GUI:
**`Gui.java`**

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Gui {

    static JPanel panel;
    static JFrame frame;
    static int count = 0;
    static boolean[] test = new boolean[1];


    public static void helper() {
        count++;

        if(count % 2 != 0) {
            test[0] = false;
        }
        else {
            test[0] = true;
        }
    }

    public static void GraphicalInterface(int[][] array, Graphics graphic) {
        int BOX_DIM = 10;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < array[0].length; j++) {
                if(array[i][j] == 0) {
                    graphic.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                }
                if(array[i][j] == 1) {
                    graphic.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                }
                if(array[i][j] == 2) {
                    graphic.setColor(Color.RED);
                }
                graphic.fillRect(i * BOX_DIM, j * BOX_DIM, BOX_DIM, BOX_DIM);
            }
        }
    }

        public static void printingOut(int[][] array)  throws InterruptedException {
        test[0] = true;

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Conway's Game of Life");
        frame.setSize(830,800);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(710, 710));
        JButton button = new JButton("Start / Stop");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                helper();
            }

        });
        frame.add(button, BorderLayout.EAST);
        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        frame.setVisible(true);


        while(true) {       
            //Printing out
            while(Gui.test[0]) {
                Graphics graphic = panel.getGraphics();
                GraphicalInterface(array, graphic);

                //Applying rules
                GameOfLife.applyRules(array);    
                Thread.sleep(249);             
            }
            Thread.sleep(1);  
        }
    }
}
```

I would appreciate any suggestions to improve my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Gui.java

1) The `panel` and  `frame` variables are unused.

```java
    static JPanel panel;
    static JFrame frame;
```

2) The `test` variable can be converted to a boolean.

```java
    static boolean test;
```

3) The `helper` method can be simplified

```java
    public static void helper() {
        test = count++ % 2 == 0;
    }
```

4) Method `GraphicalInterface`

- You should rename it to `graphicalInterface`, since the methods start with a lowercase.
- The variable `BOX_DIM` should be a class constant.

```java
    public static final int BOX_DIM = 10;
```

- In the loop, you can use an else-if or a switch case, since you can have only one choice.

```java
if (array[i][j] == 0) {
    graphic.setColor(Color.WHITE);
} else if (array[i][j] == 1) {
    graphic.setColor(Color.BLACK);
} else if (array[i][j] == 2) {
    graphic.setColor(Color.RED);
}
```

**or**

```java
if (array[i][j] == 0) {
    graphic.setColor(Color.WHITE);
} else if (array[i][j] == 1) {
    graphic.setColor(Color.BLACK);
} else if (array[i][j] == 2) {
    graphic.setColor(Color.RED);
}
```

#### GameOfLife.java

Method `applyRules`

1) Since the array is not updated during the execution of the method, I suggest that you extract the `array.length` in a variable (used 6 times).

2) You can extract `array[x][y]` in a variable.

```java
    public static void applyRules(int[][] array) {
        final int lengthOfTheArray = array.length;

        int[][] newArray = new int[lengthOfTheArray][lengthOfTheArray];

        for (int y = 1; y < lengthOfTheArray - 1; y++) {
            for (int x = 1; x < lengthOfTheArray - 1; x++) {
                int neighbors = neighborsCounter(array, x, y);

                final int currentArrayValue = array[x][y];

                if (currentArrayValue == 1) {
                    if ((neighbors < 2) || (neighbors > 3)) {
                        newArray[x][y] = 0;
                    }
                    if ((neighbors == 2) || (neighbors == 3)) {
                        newArray[x][y] = 1;
                    }
                } else if (currentArrayValue == 0) {
                    if (neighbors == 3) {
                        newArray[x][y] = 1;
                    } else {
                        newArray[x][y] = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < lengthOfTheArray - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < lengthOfTheArray - 1; j++) {
                array[i][j] = newArray[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
```

Method `neighborsCounter`

1) Instead of increasing the variable `neighbors` using `neighbors = neighbors + 1;`, you can use `neighbors++;`.

2) Same for the decrease, you can use:

```java
if (array[x][y] == 1) {
    neighbors--;
}
``
```

Answer (score 2):

You should remove all static qualifiers, so that you have real object. Maby create a Main.java with the main function so that it is your only class with static. Your distinction between Gui and GameOfLife is good and i would keep it that way. 
You can move the `int [][] array = new int [71][71];` out of the method to a field from the class GameOfLife and you should rename it to something like "gamefield" or "gamestate". 
These are the important things.

---

A little thing you can replace:

```
static int count = 0;
static boolean[] test = new boolean[1];
```

with something like:

```
boolean running = true;
```

the hole helper() can be replaced with:

```
running = !running;
```